# Adding drop downs and multi select to lists programmatically in SP 2010

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I am attempting to create two lists that are linked to each other, programmatically, on activation of my web part.

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWeb spWeb = properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
    if (spWeb != null)
    {
        // Create our Lists
        spWeb.Lists.Add("Memeber Records", "Holds a list of Memebers", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
        spWeb.Lists.Add("Certification", "Certifications and Their Descriptions", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);

        SPList list = spWeb.Lists["Memeber Records"];
        SPList certList = spWeb.Lists["Certification"];

        // Add Outr Fields
        list.Fields.Add("Memebr ID", SPFieldType.Integer, true);
        list.Fields.Add("Memeber Name", SPFieldType.Text, true);
        // were missing a item - a drop down with static content such as: Association, Company, Head Office
        list.Fields.Add("Memeber Certification", SPFieldType.Lookup, false);

        list.Update();

        certList.Fields.Add("Certfication Title", SPFieldType.Text, true);
        certList.Fields.Add("Description", SPFieldType.Text, true); // This one should be a text box allowing 256 characters

        certList.Update();
    }
}
```

As you can see I am needing your help to figure out how to create a couple more things:

- I need a drop down with static content in it as a field. But `.Fields.Add()` doesn't have a drop down feature in `list`
- `certList`'s second  field is suppose to be a text box with up to 250 characte's if not more.
- How do I link `certList` to `list` such that when selecting a member certification it pulls from the `certtList`

Is there anything else that I am missing to have this work upon activation of this web part? I scoped it to **site** but when deploying (when I created the project, I selected) its **Farm** instead of **Sandbox**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the choice field. The list.Fields.Add has a overload where you can populate the choices too. I haven't tried it but this is specifically for choice fields.